# Tensorflow equivalent of numpy.fill()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I cannot find the equivalent of [numpy's fill function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.fill.html) in Tensorflow. Tensorflow has a [fill function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/fill), but it is not equivalent. Specifically, the tensorflow function returns a new, constant tensor.

I have a `tf.Variable`, and I want to set all of the entries to some constant value before an iteration. What function or idiom accomplishes this?

Note that I want to use this function multiple times. We are not talking about a one and done iteration. So for instance, I COULD do something like this:

```
tf.Variable( tf.fill( ... ) )
tf.Variable( tf.ones( ... ) )
```

but that would result in a lot of temporary variables being created. I would prefer to create the variable once, and then reset it using a `fill`. Unless you there is a reason that is bad from an efficiency point of view...?

Answer (score 1):

You could first determine the shape of your tensor using [`shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape), and then use the `constant` or `fill` methods.

```
>>> mytf = tf.ones([2,3], tf.int32)
>>> mynew1 = tf.constant(3, shape = mytf.shape)
>>> mynew2 = tf.fill(mytf.shape, 4)
>>> print(sess.run(mytf))
[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]]
>>> print(sess.run(mynew1))
[[3 3 3]
 [3 3 3]]
>>> print(sess.run(mynew2))
[[4 4 4]
 [4 4 4]]
```

Comment: The fill method will not work because I need a mutable object, and the fill object is constant. The entire point is to avoid creating temporary variables

Comment: What's the difference between the `fill` and `constant`?